# C FTP upload code uploads doesn't work properly

Tags: c, windows, gcc, wininet

I have written above code using wininet to upload a file to ftp server.
code works properly sometimes and it uploads the `file.txt` file completely to the server but sometimes i get corrupted `file.txt` file(i.e i get only some part of the file ). why this problem is occurring ? how to make sure that i get complete file( without any lost data of the file).
Im using windows, gcc compiler in codeblocks.

```
BOOL uploadFile()
{
        BOOL t = false;
        HINTERNET hint,hftp;
        hint = InternetOpen("FTP",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,0,0,INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC);
        hftp = InternetConnect(hint,"ftp.someaddress.com",INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT,"myusername","mypassword",INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP,INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE,0);
        t = FtpPutFile(hftp,"C:\\file.txt","/file.txt",FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY ,0);
        InternetCloseHandle(hftp);
        InternetCloseHandle(hint);
        return t;
}
```

Comment: change `INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC` to `0`. Show error messages, `GetLastError` etc.

Comment: And `C:\file.txt` needs escaping